# Finding Matching records based on two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like below:

```
Table A (SSN, Date)
1234 01/01/2016,
4567 12/10/2016,
1233 10/09/2016,
2344 11/10/2016,
5765 06/05/2016,
5657 09/25/2016,
3434 03/12/2016,
8768 01/20/2017,
4353 05/29/2017,
6878 07/30/2017,
3242 03/01/2017,
3467 01/11/2017,

Table B (SSN, Date)
1234 01/01/2016,
4567 12/10/2016,
1233 10/09/2016,
2344 10/09/2016,
2344 10/09/2016,
5765 08/12/2016,
5657 11/30/2016,
3434 03/12/2016,
8768 01/20/2017,
4353 05/29/2017,
6878 07/30/2017,
3242 03/01/2017,
3467 01/11/2017,
1233 02/01/2016,
1233 12/09/2017,
3434 12/11/2016,
3434 01/01/2016
```

SSN and date columns are just two of many columns, I need to treat Table A as base column as I need to pull out entire record for that SSN based on below conditions. 
I want to compare SSN and Date column from Table A with Table B.

- Retain the Matching SSNs and Dates from Table A and Table B.
- If Matching records are not found, then retain the Date value of that SSN from Table A and search for min(Date) for that SSN from Table B and also Max(Date) from Table B.

So far, I have this query, but hit a roadblock, it sounds like its similar to Vlookup like in Excel based on two columns. Any help would be very appreciated.

In this query, as of now I am just trying to get True or False values, if there is match and no match, then I need to incorporate above conditions.

```
select s.SSN, S.Date,
   (case when ns.Date is null then 'False' else 'TRUE' end)

   from TableA s 
   left outer join 
   (select SSN, Date from TableB ) ns

on s.(SSN) = ns.SSN 
   and s.PPED = ns.Date
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide desired results.

Comment: What would be the result if there's no match for `SSN`? What is `PPED` and why are you comparing it to `TableB.Date`?

Comment: @Josh Part  -- Sorry, it was a type, it should have been S.Date instead of S.PPED.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the easiest way is going to be just with some subqueries.

```
SELECT
    a.SSN
,   a.Date
,   CASE WHEN b.Date IS NULL THEN (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM TableB x WHERE a.SSN = x.SSN) END  AS MinDate
,   CASE WHEN b.Date IS NULL THEN (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM TableB x WHERE a.SSN = x.SSN) END  AS MaxDate
FROM TableA a
    LEFT JOIN TableB b
        ON  a.SSN = b.SSN
        AND a.Date = b.Date
```

That will display the min and max dates from TableB when it does not match the exact date from TableA.

Hopefully it is at least enough to get you started.  The other option would be to fudge some joins against MIN/MAX subqueries instead.

```
SELECT
    a.SSN
,   a.Date
,   CASE WHEN b.Date IS NULL THEN MinDate END   AS MinDate
,   CASE WHEN b.Date IS NULL THEN MaxDate END   AS MaxDate
FROM TableA a
    LEFT JOIN TableB b
        ON  a.SSN = b.SSN
        AND a.Date = b.Date
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SSN, MIN(Date) AS MinDate
        FROM TableB
        GROUP BY SSN
    ) mn
        ON a.SSN = mn.SSN
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SSN, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
        FROM TableB
        GROUP BY SSN
    ) mx
        ON a.SSN = mx.SSN
```

I don't know what seems more readable to you.  There's probably a bunch more ways to do it too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful to get me started. Since, Data is too big and its taking lot of time to run and get these results, I am going to try this out on a sample records.

Comment: Thank you for the above query,Instead of Max and Min dates, I am also looking for records below:  "For each Record in Table A (I.,e SSN and Date), I am trying to find the record which matches the exact record in Table B, if not then record with previous date for the same SSN and also the next Date for that SSN from Table B Both previous and next date will be comparing to the date of the record we pick from Table A. I hope I was able to explain, please revert if I am unclear. I think , with this logic, I will be able to proceed to a larger query that I am working on. Thanks again fr help